# Android context over the whole application

Tags: android, android-context

this question is intended to ask to the community if the approach i've taken for my app is correct or may have some side effect:

I've created:
- an Activity, called MasterAcitity, extended from every activity in my app. The application tag in the manifest is declared as follow

```
<application
        android:name="my.package.name.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ApplicationStyle" >
```

- A class, called MyApplication, that extends android.App.Application, which has the following code

  ```
  private static Context _context;

  public static Context getContext() {
      return _context;
  }

  public static void setContext(Context context) {
      _context = context;
  }
  ```
- In the manifest the application tag is declared as follow

  ```
  <application
      android:name="my.package.name.MyApplication"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/ApplicationStyle" >
  ```

MasterActivity executes this code in OnResume and OnCreate methods

```
MyApplication.setContext(this);
```

Every activity of the app extends MasterActivity.

There is a class in the app, called DialogHelper which has a static method

```
public static void showDialog(String message)
```

which uses `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` to create and show a dialog using as context `MyApplication.getContext()`

so from everywhere in my app i can use

```
DialogHelper.showDialog("my message");
```

Is this approach going to work? or i need to pay attention to something?

My doubt is on the static context...

Thanks

Comment: you can use getaplicationcontext(). did you tried that ?

Comment: you have to pass the context when needed. This may cause memory leaks.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys, i have some classes with static methods which should show dialogs
Anis, can you explain me why it should cause memory leaks?

Comment: @SimonVeloper : "i have some classes with static methods which should show dialogs" - Out of interest what do those 'classes' extend?

Comment: just pass the context as the arguments while accessing those classes

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach going to work?

Using an `Application` for UI work has a history of causing problems. Either use an `Activity`, or a specialized `Context` for a given set of circumstances (e.g., `getThemedContext()` on `ActionBar`, `getContext()` on a `Presentation`).

Comment: I agree with you, but what i don't undestand is why this approach can cause some problem. 
What i do not undestand is the difference of passing the context from the current activity invoking the method and letting the static method showDialog take the context which is always updated from every activity (by the moment that the onCreate method sets the context).  

Don't I'm taking the same context reference?

Comment: @SimonVeloper: Actually, your approach is worse, IMHO, than what I had been thinking. I misread your post and though that the `Context` being held by the `Application` was the `Application`. Do not put other `Context` objects in static data members, as you risk a memory leak. Besides, for a `Dialog`, since they can only be started by an `Activity`, just use `this` for the `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a `onDestroy` handler that resets the context to null if the context belongs to the activity beeing destroyed.

Instead of a global static context i would prefer a api like this

```
 DialogHelper.showDialog(this.getContext(),"my message");
```

[Updated 5.5.2013]

Every Activity, Service <strike>, BroadcastReceiver</strike> is [indirectly derived from Context via ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) and other classes like Views save and use Context. they normally expose it through a getContext() function. So the context should be available where neccessary.

Comment: Firstly, `BroadcastReceiver` does NOT extend `Context`. Secondly `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` do not have a method called `getContext()`. Finally why would a class which extends `Context` need a method to get an instance of itself? Anything which extends `Context` can simply use `this` to pass a `Context` instance to another class.

Comment: you are right in that a BroadcastReceiver is not a context. I updated my answer and reformulated the last part to make more clear, what i meant